# Creating a secondary network specific to one room

Tags: networking, gaming

If I'm asking a repeat question my apologies, please redirect me. I believe what I'm attempting to do is create a secondary network. My home has a number of computers connecting to the same Wi-Fi signal, so I receive a slow connection, this is also in part to the layout of my home. I want a better connection to the Wi-Fi for gaming, a wired connection to the network is not an option. This proposed secondary network will primarily be hosting my console, but my phone, computer (I don't use often), and laptop will connect as well. What is required?

Comment: You've ruled out the absolute best way and that is to install a second wireless access point via a wired link back to the router.  That leaves a wireless repeater.  There are two categories of those, technology that uses the same channel as the source, and those (better but more expensive) that use different channels and/or bands for the back haul to the router.  There are also power-line adapters that may or may not work for you.  Other than that this is almost a shopping question which would be off topic.  Oh by the way, you likely don't want a secondary network, but a second access point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single-bullet solution to this problem, but I put to you you are going about solving it the wrong way.

Might I suggest first finding the bottleneck, then working out how to solve it.    I would try answer the following questions as the first stage -

1. What WIFI technology are you using, and how are the devices communicating
   with it.  For example 802.11ac is better then 802.11n is better then
   802.11g.
2. Is the problem that you are trying to put too much down 1 frequency or
   is the issue noise related.  (If you have an android device WIFI Analyser
   is a cool tool to help you scope out whats going on)
3. Should you be using the 2.4 gig band or the 5 gig band or both?
4. Should you be using high gain or directional aerials, does your AP handle
   MIMO or equivalent, and are your computers taking advantage of it.
5. Should you be shielding your environment from external/stray RF or
   using Ethernet over Power Devices and/or setting up multiple AP's to
   increase your signal strength.

Once you know your environment and its bottlenecks, then you can start looking at solutions, however simply creating a second network won't fix the issue unless you know its related to the frequency you are using, and that by using multiple frequencies you will be able to get better performance - That is by no means a given or even likely.